# Delayed result in multiplication table in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function setQuantity(upordown) {
    num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
    num2 = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    document.getElementById("Inputresult").value = num1 * num2;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
    if (quantity.value > 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++document.getElementById('quantity').value;}
          
        else if (upordown == 'down'){--document.getElementById('quantity').value;}
        }
          
        
    else if (quantity.value == 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++document.getElementById('quantity').value;}
        }
        
    else
        {
        document.getElementById('quantity').value=1;
        }
       
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="firstNumber" value="5" readonly/>

<div class="order-option">
          Quantity:
          <span id="quantity-field">
              <input type="button" value="-" id="down" onclick="setQuantity('down');" >
              <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="0">
              <input type="button" value="+" id="up" onclick="setQuantity('up');">
          </span>
</div>

<p>The Result is : <br>
<input type="text" id = "Inputresult" value="" name="total" > </p>
```

I am working multiplication in html, I don't know why the result is delayed but the syntax I get is right, please  help me on how to configured this problem. , please check the snippet i provide in this question. thank you in advance to those who will help me to configure this problem.

```
  <input type="text" id="firstNumber" value="5" readonly/>

  <div class="order-option">
      Quantity:
      <span id="quantity-field">
          <input type="button" value="-" id="down" onclick="setQuantity('down');" >
          <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="1" onkeyup="multiplyBy()">
          <input type="button" value="+" id="up" onclick="setQuantity('up');" onclick="multiplyBy()">
      </span>
  </div>

 <input type="text" id = "Inputresult" value="" name="total" >


<script>
    function setQuantity(upordown) {
    num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
    num2 = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    document.getElementById("Inputresult").value = num1 * num2;
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
    if (quantity.value > 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++document.getElementById('quantity').value;}
        else if (upordown == 'down'){--document.getElementById('quantity').value;}
        }
    else if (quantity.value == 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++document.getElementById('quantity').value;}
        }
    else
        {
        document.getElementById('quantity').value=1;
        }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You set the result before you increment the quantity causing a mismatch in the multiplication. You need to switch your code around so you do the increment/decrement of the quantity before you do the setting of your result. PLease see my fiddle: (https://jsfiddle.net/rp0fz4dn/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    function setQuantity(upordown) {
   
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
    if (quantity.value > 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++document.getElementById('quantity').value;}
        else if (upordown == 'down'){--document.getElementById('quantity').value;}
        }
    else if (quantity.value == 1) {
        if (upordown == 'up'){++document.getElementById('quantity').value;}
        }
    else
        {
        document.getElementById('quantity').value=1;
        }
    num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
    num2 = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    document.getElementById("Inputresult").value = num1 * num2;
}
</script>
```

Change your code like above ,

```
num1 = document.getElementById("firstNumber").value;
    num2 = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    document.getElementById("Inputresult").value = num1 * num2;
```

the above code part should be in last part, because we need to access values in the text after increment